# converting id into nsstring

Tags: iphone

i am using NSPropertyListSerialization  for converting nsdictionary to xml and the code is as follows

```
NSMutableDictionary *rootObj = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];
    NSDictionary *innerDict;
    NSString *name;
    NSDate *dob;
    NSArray *scores;

    scores = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:6],
              [NSNumber numberWithFloat:4.6], [NSNumber numberWithLong:6.0000034], nil];
    name = @"George Washington";
    dob = [NSDate dateWithString:@"1732-02-17 04:32:00 +0300"];
    innerDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                 [NSArray arrayWithObjects: name, dob, scores, nil]
                                            forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name", @"DOB", @"Scores"]];
    [rootObj setObject:innerDict forKey:@"Washington"];

    scores = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:8],
              [NSNumber numberWithFloat:4.9],
              [NSNumber numberWithLong:9.003433], nil];
    name = @"Abraham Lincoln";
    dob = [NSDate dateWithString:@"1809-02-12 13:18:00 +0400"];
    innerDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                 [NSArray arrayWithObjects: name, dob, scores, nil]
                                            forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name", @"DOB", @"Scores"]];
    [rootObj setObject:innerDict forKey:@"Lincoln"];


    NSLog(@"the dictionary is :%@",rootObj);


    id plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:(id)rootObj
                                                          format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:nil];

NSLog(@ "the xml file is :%@",plist);
```

and the out put in console is as follows......

```
XmltoNSDictionary[2478:207] the dictionary is :{
    Lincoln =     {
        DOB = "1809-02-12 09:18:00 +0000";
        Name = "Abraham Lincoln";
        Scores =         (
            8,
            "4.9",
            9
        );
    };
    Washington =     {
        DOB = "1732-02-17 01:32:00 +0000";
        Name = "George Washington";
        Scores =         (
            6,
            "4.6",
            6
        );
    };
}
```

> 2011-08-22 11:35:09.611 XmltoNSDictionary[2478:207] the xml file is
>   :<3c3f786d 6c207665 7273696f 6e3d2231 2e302220 656e636f 64696e67
>   3d225554 462d3822 3f3e0a3c 21444f43 54595045 20706c69 73742050
>   55424c49 4320222d 2f2f4170 706c652f 2f445444 20504c49 53542031
>   2e302f2f 454e2220 22687474 703a2f2f 7777772e 6170706c 652e636f
>   6d2f4454 44732f50 726f7065 7274794c 6973742d 312e302e 64746422
>   3e0a3c70 6c697374 20766572 73696f6e 3d22312e 30223e0a 3c646963
>   743e0a09 3c6b6579 3e4c696e 636f6c6e 3c2f6b65 793e0a09 3c646963
>   743e0a09 093c6b65 793e444f 423c2f6b 65793e0a 09093c64 6174653e
>   31383039 2d30322d 31325430 393a3138 3a30305a 3c2f6461 74653e0a
>   09093c6b 65793e4e 616d653c 2f6b6579 3e0a0909 3c737472 696e673e
>   41627261 68616d20 4c696e63 6f6c6e3c 2f737472 696e673e 0a09093c
>   6b65793e 53636f72 65733c2f 6b65793e 0a09093c 61727261 793e0a09
>   09093c69 6e746567 65723e38 3c2f696e 74656765 723e0a09 09093c72
>   65616c3e 342e3930 30303030 30393533 36373433 31363c2f 7265616c
>   3e0a0909 093c696e 74656765 723e393c 2f696e74 65676572 3e0a0909
>   3c2f6172 7261793e 0a093c2f 64696374 3e0a093c 6b65793e 57617368
>   696e6774 6f6e3c2f 6b65793e 0a093c64 6963743e 0a09093c 6b65793e
>   444f423c 2f6b6579 3e0a0909 3c646174 653e3137 33322d30 322d3137
>   5430313a 33323a30 305a3c2f 64617465 3e0a0909 3c6b6579 3e4e616d
>   653c2f6b 65793e0a 09093c73 7472696e 673e4765 6f726765 20576173
>   68696e67 746f6e3c 2f737472 696e673e 0a09093c 6b65793e 53636f72
>   65733c2f 6b65793e 0a09093c 61727261 793e0a09 09093c69 6e746567
>   65723e36 3c2f696e 74656765 723e0a09 09093c72 65616c3e 342e3539
>   39393939 39303436 33323536 38343c2f 7265616c 3e0a0909 093c696e
>   74656765 723e363c 2f696e74 65676572 3e0a0909 3c2f6172 7261793e
>   0a093c2f 64696374 3e0a3c2f 64696374 3e0a3c2f 706c6973 743e0a>

now i want to do is that to display id in xml (nsstring) format ....

can any one please help me how to do that ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the end of your code snippet:

```
NSString *plistString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plist encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"the plist is: %@", plistString);

2011-08-21 23:32:49.324 so7143762iPhone[5474:207] the plist is: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Lincoln</key>
    <dict>
        <key>DOB</key>
        <date>1809-02-12T09:18:00Z</date>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Abraham Lincoln</string>
        <key>Scores</key>
        <array>
            <integer>8</integer>
            <real>4.9000000953674316</real>
            <integer>9</integer>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>Washington</key>
    <dict>
        <key>DOB</key>
        <date>1732-02-17T01:32:00Z</date>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>George Washington</string>
        <key>Scores</key>
        <array>
            <integer>6</integer>
            <real>4.5999999046325684</real>
            <integer>6</integer>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Also, in OS X I need to add `nil` to the end of the lists in the calls to `arrayWithObjects`. I assume it's the same for iOS.

Comment: I just tried in an iPhone app and, yes, you do need to conclude the lists with `nil`. It doesn't crash, but you get the warning "Missing sentinel in function call"

Comment: Also, this is a good example of how floating point doesn't represent decimal fractions exactly.

Comment: and i have another question is it possible to edit the header tag of the xml file  ie    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">  i dont want to display this tag in my  xml file...   is it possible.....

Comment: If you have another question, you should post it as a question. Comments aren't the correct place for questions.